# Flutter: filter list as per some condition

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, filter

I'm having a list of movies. That contains all animated and non-animated movies. To identify whether it's Animated or not there is one flag called `isAnimated`.

I want to show only Animated movies. How can I do that?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

`toList()` is missing to materializer the result

```
_AnimatedMovies = AllMovies.where((i) => i.isAnimated).toList();
```

Comment: No work here :( . It says type 'Where Iterable<>' is not a subtype of type 'List

Comment: If you need a `List` add `.toList()`

Comment: It worked like charm actually I was creating an app in which I have some static data (list of a model) and when I am navigating to a single view page I am sending the id of the model and I am finding the model by id and showing it's data in the single view page.
I am doing like this
```CompanyModel company = companies.where((c) => c.id == companyId).toList().first;```

Comment: What would be the null safe version of this?

Comment: @JoelGMathew I think `AllMovies.whereNotNull().where((i) => i.isAnimated).toList();` (not tested)

Answer (score 28):

**The Solution is here**

> Just try with this Function getCategoryList(),
> Here the condition will be catogory_id == '1' from the list

```
List<dynamic> getCategoryList(List<dynamic> inputlist) {
    List outputList = inputlist.where((o) => o['category_id'] == '1').toList();
    return outputList;
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this for specific condition

```
List<String> strings = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
List<String> filteredStrings  = strings.where((item) {
   return item.length == 3;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

where function on a List returns Iterable, you have to convert it to List using the function List.from(Iterable).

So in the above scenario, you should use the following code snippet.

```
Iterable _AnimatedMoviesIterable = AllMovies.where((i) => i.isAnimated);

_AnimatedMovies = List.from(_AnimatedMoviesIterable);
```

Edited:

As per Günter Zöchbauer solution, we can use a single line instead of multiple. So the code is

```
_AnimatedMovies = AllMovies.where((i) => i.isAnimated).toList();
```

Comment: Iterables have a `toList()` method which is much easier to read IMHO.

Comment: Agreed @GünterZöchbauer. We can use AllMovies.where((i) => i.isAnimated).toList(); as you mentioned