# Exclude document from query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, can't really find any direct answers anywhere to get around it. I really appreciate any help and more practical code to understand this.

I'm querying documents from a collection in Firestore. Then I'm putting them inside a custom List:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await cardRef.limit(10).getDocuments();
    List<CustomCard> cards =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => CustomCard.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
```

Then I display the list like so:

```
//if cards != null
return Stack(children: cards);
```

However, I need to block documents from being added to 'cards' IF they contain a key inside a map of 'keys'.

I've tried to do something like this unsuccessfully:

```
if(snapshot.documents.contains('keys.$currentUserid'))
//dont add to list
```

But someone said on my previous post here, that I should hide the card on the client side. Is that the best approach since that card would still be added to the list? How would I do that?

*in sum: 1) get all documents from a collection, 2) check each for specific key, 3) if they don't have key, add to list.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `snapshot.documents`, which is a [`List<DocumentSnapshot>` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/documents.html). So what you're looking for is a way to derive another list from `snapshot.documents` with some of the documents removed.

My initial search for that [`flutter filter list`](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+filter+list), which shows that [`List.where`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/where.html) is what you should be using for that. A simple example on this site: [Flutter: Filter list as per some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition)

So that'd lead to something like:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await cardRef.limit(10).getDocuments();
List<DocumentSnapshot> filtered = snapshot.documents.where((doc) => ... /* your filter goes here */ )
List<CustomCard> cards = filtered.map((doc) => CustomCard.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
```