# how to filter a list with condition in dart

Tags: dart

I have a list and I want to put a condition on it. for example, I want to have items from list `lst` that value greater than 10:

```
var lst = [{"value":5 , "name":"test1"},
           {"value":12 , "name":"test2"},
           {"value":8 , "name":"test3"},
           {"value":23 , "name":"test4"}];

/*
output: value greater than 10 => 
    [{"value":12 , "name":"test2"},
     {"value":23 , "name":"test4"}]
*/
```

Comment: It's a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition

Comment: @ocheriaf I saw this question but I'm not working flutter. It's very complicated and a lot of explanation and I don't understand it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either use the `where` function on iterables to filter its elements, then convert the resulting iterable back to a list, or use the list literal syntax, or a combination of the two where you "spread" the result of `where`:

```
var list = [ ... ];
var filtered1 = list.where((e) => e["value"] > 10).toList();
var filtered2 = [for (var e in list) if (e["value"] > 10) e];
var filtered3 = [... list.where((e) => e["value"] > 10)];
```

Answer (score 3):

To filter a list base on a condition you can use [List.where](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) which takes a test function and returns a new Iterable that contains the elements that match the test.

To get a list with only the values greater than 10 you can filter you list of maps as such:

```
lst.where((e) => e['value'] > 10); //Returns a lazy Iterable
```

if you need to modify your list later you can append a `.toList()`, to get a new list.

Answer (score 2):

try to use this code:

```
  List lst = [{"value":5 , "name":"test1"}  ,{"value":12 , "name":"test2"}  , {"value":8 , "name":"test3"}  , {"value":23 , "name":"test4"} ];
  List newLst = lst.where( (o) => o['value'] > 5).toList();

  print(newLst);
```

Answer (score 1):

**> Just try this Function, catogory_id == 1 is condition here**

```
List<dynamic> chooseCatogory(List<dynamic> list) {
    List newlist = list.where((o) => o['category_id'] == '1').toList();
    return newlist;
  }
```