# How to create a new variable with a list of items including only by the key

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List productsList =[{
'name':'Nike air max',
'category:'Shoes',
'brand':'Nike'
}'{
'name':'Adidas Shoes',
'category:'Shoes',
'brand':'Adidas'
}'{
'name':'Nike Shirt',
'category:'Shirts',
'brand':'Nike'
}'{
'name':'Adidas Shirt',
'category:'Shirt',
'brand':'Adidas'
}']
```

I want to create a new list from `productsList` that contains only the products with `Shirt` as category and a new list that contains both `Shirt` as category and `Nike` as brand.
Like
List shirtProducts= (All products of productsList that have Shirt as category)
List nikeShirtProducts= (All products of productsList that have both Shiet as category and Nike as brand)

How can I do that?

Comment: use the map method to do a projection over your first list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nikeShirtProducts = productsList.where((i) => (i.brand == Nike)).toList();
```

ckeckout this post
[it might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition)

Comment: it would be nice if you mark this question as right if it worked for you. So that others will know the answer immediately.