# Search inside the List<Map> in flutter dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, search

I want to filter the List by searching in the search bar but it does not work.

```
for (var map in offersList) {
      if (map.containsKey("foodname")) {
        if (map["foodname"] == query) {
          setState(() {
            offersList.clear();
            offersList.add(map);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition . Use the .where method of the list since its much simpler and more efficient in terms of speed. If .where doesn't fit for you, there are other methods that filter the list as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a forEach

```
    offersList.forEach((map){
      if (map.containsKey("foodname")) {
        if (map["foodname"] == query) {
          setState(() {
            offersList.clear();
            offersList.add(map);
          });
        }
      }
});
```