# Flutter filtter data with a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array like this

```
                 "penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "53dd7ece-9e4b-4ed9-8520-6dd13dafd3b7",
                        "name": "Speeding",
                        "instances": 16,
                        "score": 100,
                        "max": 100,
                        "cost": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5a053667-2c29-4eeb-bf64-06a27214106f",
                        "name": "Braking",
                        "instances": 3,
                        "score": 15,
                        "max": 100,
                        "cost": 0
                    }
                ]
```

I am showing instances simply in the text widget. But I need to filter it by Speeding. You can see right now I have 2 arrays and 1 has the name Speeding. I need to print the instances which have the name Speeding.

The issue is I can show like add [0] and show in Text but sometimes Speeding comes in the second array so I need to find a way to show the instance only which has the name speeding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Filter list as per some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition)

Answer (score 1):

you can use where method to get only specific deta.

example:

```
var fullObject = {"penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "53dd7ece-9e4b-4ed9-8520-6dd13dafd3b7",
                        "name": "Speeding",
                        "instances": 16,
                        "score": 100,
                        "max": 100,
                        "cost": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5a053667-2c29-4eeb-bf64-06a27214106f",
                        "name": "Braking",
                        "instances": 3,
                        "score": 15,
                        "max": 100,
                        "cost": 0
                    }
                ]};
  ;
  var penelties =  fullObject['penalties'];
  
  print(penelties.where((oldValue) => "Speeding" == (oldValue['name'].toString())));
```

your ans is :

```
penelties.where((oldValue) => "Speeding" == (oldValue['name'].toString()));
```