# Flutter Firebase ArrayContains Where Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

```
 var searchRef = _firestore
        .collection("vehicles")
        .where("models.plane", isEqualTo: "true")
        .where("models.bus", isEqualTo: "true");
```

In this query method I can query multiple value but I want to do this dynamically. If the user enters the plane, I want to query the plane or if the user enters the plane and the bus, I want to query the plane and the bus, or if the user enters the plane, bus and sports car, I want to query the plane, bus and sports car. That is, the number of variables to be queried and the variables will vary from user to user.

How can I convert this code to dynamic code.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible at the moment. You would have to fetch documents containing either of those values and then manually filter them in your Flutter app.

You just need to pass that array as the value of `arrayContains`.

```
var sRef = _firestore
           .collection("vehicles1")
           .where("models", arrayContains: item);
```

This query will return all the documents in `vehicles` collection where the array `models` contain either of the items in the array you pass. Then you can filter through that array and check which documents' models array contains all those items.

You can check this answer: [Flutter filter list as per given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to return the documents which contains all the array items.

so for that I would suggest.

```
List<String> item = ["motor", "car", "plane"];

var sRef = sRef = _firestore
          .collection("vehicles1");

for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      
          sref = sref.where("models", arrayContains: item[i]);
}

// finally

print(sref.snapshotChanges()) //something like this
```

basically what above code will do is
it will generate a complex query something like

```
_firestore.collection("vehicles").where("models", arrayContains: item[0]).where("models", arrayContains: item[1]).where("models", arrayContains: item[2]) //... and so on till for loop ends
```

Comment: The documentation says, You can use at most one array-contains clause per query

Comment: Seems like one of the native problems of the firebase features. OK give me some time, there might be some chance if you change your database schema. Let me figure out an way around.

Comment: Can you tell me the use case of above approach ? Like I am trying to get to know what you really want to achieve with your schema.