# Add SearchBar in Appbar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar

I would like to search by 'id'. I have seen videos that does this by creating a new class with the data, but my data is directly extracted from a Json file and I do not know how to search with this structure. I have already displayed the icon in AppBar, I just need to look up by 'id'. Please help!

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Info'),
          actions: [IconButton(onPressed: (){
         String query='What to write here?',
         final filterdata = data.where((i) => 
            i['id'].toString().contains(query)).toList();
            }, }, 
        icon: Icon(Icons.search))],
        ),
        body: Center(
          
          child: FutureBuilder(
            
            future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('files/details.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Decode the JSON
              var newData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

              return ListView.builder(
                
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    elevation: 49,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 32, bottom: 32, left: 16, right: 16),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => LoginPage()));
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                
                                  **newData[index]['id'],**
                                  //'Note Title',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      fontSize: 22),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          //SizedBox(width: 20),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: newData == null ? 0 : newData.length,
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And my Json data looks like this:

{"id": "3321", "name": "John"}

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something based on a user click on the `IconButton`
The `onPressed` is exactly where you will put your code relating to the search mechanism

You can use the `where` function for the dart `List` class. Do not forget to use `toList` to convert the result returned by this function to a `List`. An example for which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578529/flutter-filter-list-as-per-some-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `newData` looks a bit like this:

```dart
[
    {
        id: 12,
        data: {}
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        data: {}
    }
]
```

You could filter the array using `where`.

```dart
String searchQuery = ...
final filteredData = newData.where((item) => item.id.toString().contains(searchQuery)).toList();
```

And then use `filteredData` to display those items only.

If this is not how your `newData` object looks, consider adding a sample to your question.

Comment: I have edited the post with your suggestions, I just need a little bit more help to get it done. THanks!